ERROR: "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
my name is Iran, im new at delevopment and i want to use github.
Can someone help me to send my html project to github repository?
I tried to send to github repository in cmd excatly the way that repository shows, but the message that i receive is: 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Please share the exact command you're running. Did you install git anyhow?

do u have installed git?
If not, download at this link: https://git-scm.com/downloads
If your operating system, u need to install the same of the system-icon (linux, macOS or Windows)
When u download the exec, do double-click on archive, and press next untill it's installed.
When it happens, open your archive > right-click > gith-bash here.
(remember, u need to have a repositore in github)
get the link of the repositore, then write these commands on git-bash here:
git init
git add . (. is to select the whole archive)
git branch -M main
git commit -m "details what u did on the archive"
git remote add origin (put ur copied link repositore)
git push -u origin main
when u do other commit at the same repositore do this:
git add .
git commit -m "details what u did on the archive"
git push
